# Error: A1163E Unknown Opcode R0, expecting opcode or Macro with instruction in the left column

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32f4, armasm

Today I've been getting this error in my code stating:

RTE\Device\STM32F407VGTx\startup_stm32f407xx.s(191): A1163E: Unknown opcode R0, expecting opcode or macro

Here is the area of code where it stops at:

[image: Error]

I have not performed any assembly in the code that I have written, which seems like a common reason why this message appears. Would anyone be kind enough to help me troubleshoot this issue? This is my first time programming with an STM32F4 board, so I am not entirely sure where to begin looking :(

Comment: Looks like an indentation problem, is that compiler generated code?

Comment: Yes, it is compiler generated code!

Comment: Have you accidentally created two "main.s" file?

Answer (score 4):

I took a break from looking at my code, and when I came back, I randomly pressed TAB before the LDR statement and the code can now successfully compile with 0 errors and 0 warnings!

Comment: In some assemblers, anything in the left-most column is assumed to be a label, not a mnemonic, even if it *is* also a valid mnemonic.  Apparently ARMasm is one of those assemblers.  GNU assembler is not; you'd need `ldr:` to define a symbol called `ldr`, otherwise it would be assumed to be an instruction.