# Receiving an "unknown opcode loop" error when trying to run this Assembly code

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm currently trying to place a for loop (which is not complete) inside of an if statement and I'm now receiving this error.

> "Assembly_Lab_04.s", line 16 (column 3): Error: A1163E: Unknown opcode loop , expecting opcode or Macro
>
> 16 0000001c   loop

```
 __main
    
    MOV R0, #0
    MOV R1, #3
    MOV R2, #15
    MOV R3, #0
    MOV R4, #0
    MOV R5, #0
    
    CMP R1, R2
    BLE goToIf

        loop
        ADD R4, R1, R2
        ADD R3, R3, R4
        CMP R5, R1
        ADDLE R0, R0, #1
        BLE loop

goToElse
    ADD R3, R1, R2
    
    END
```

Comment: put labels like `loop` at the beginning of the line, no preceding spaces

Comment: Although many people will notice you're writing ARM assembly looking at your code, you have to specify what machine architecture you're dealing with. There is no just *assembly* language.

Comment: If that doesn't work, following the label with a `,` or a `:` might work, as in `loop,` or `loop:`

Comment: Related: [Error: A1163E Unknown Opcode R0, expecting opcode or Macro with instruction in the left column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36253531) - seems the assembler that uses that error-number cares about indenting to distinguish label from mnemonic.